# Ctrl+Alt+L selects the file in solution explorer, but does not scroll to it

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, pressing Ctrl+Alt+L selects the file in solution explorer, but does not scroll to it. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: Ctrl+Alt+L ---> Arrow key.

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea :)
Right arrow didn't work for me, but down, down, up works every second time :D (the other time there is a border around one of the first few projects in the solution, so I have to press arrow, escape first ...)

Comment: Not quite perfect, because now the current file is at the top of SE windows, instead of the mindle.

Comment: IIRC this was a bug in solution excplorer set to auto hide.    
It is fixed in later versions of VS.